# Does my network have shared or distributed memory

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, shared-memory

Now I have some code that I would like to parallelize. The easiest thing would be to use openmp which will take advantage of the multiple processors and their cores and their shared memory. I have access to a network that I use for number crunching. I don't know if the memory on it is shared or distributed. How can I find this out? If it is shared then I can easily use openmp and it will work. I do less /proc/cpuinfo and I see that I have 8 processors available on the network. and I do less/proc/meminfo and it tells me I have  32000mega bytes of memory.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a computer, not a network.

Comment: If you're not using MPI, you're not doing clustering with OpenMP.  Are you using MPI?  You don't specify.  Also, you're ***definitely*** looking at your own machine when you do anything with `/proc`.

Comment: I logged in to the server and did /proc/meminfo there. Can that much memory (32000 mega bytes ) be installed on a single computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenMP you are probably writing your software to your machine only, as it is targeted on making the use of parallel programming transparent to the user. You can use OpenMP on a cluster together with MPI or with some OpenMP extension to make the many computers of the network appear to your OpenMP program like a single one.